# How do I label a loop arrow in tikz-cd?

Tags: labels, overleaf, tikz-cd

How do I add a label to a loop arrow in tikz-cd? I want to label loop arrows as "id". Code snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
M \arrow{r}{\iota_1} \arrow{d}{\iota_2} & G_1 \arrow[shift left=0.8ex]{ld}{g_1} \arrow[loop right]\\
G_2 \arrow{ru}{g_2} \arrow[loop below]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

My goal:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
M \ar[r, "\iota_1"] \ar[d, "\iota_2"] 
    & G_1 \ar[ld, shift left, "g_1"] \ar[loop right, "id"]\\
G_2 \ar[ru, shift left, "g_2"] \ar[loop below, "id"]
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
To follow suggestion in the @Sebastian comment, here is an example of wee bit effort to prettify above suggested solution:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[sep=large,
 every cell/.append style = {inner sep=2pt}, 
every label/.append style = {inner sep=1pt},
every arrow/.append style = {-{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}},
                    ]
M \ar[r, "\iota_1"] \ar[d, "\iota_2" '] 
    & G_1 \ar[ld, shift left=1.5pt, "g_1"] \ar[looseness=4, out=30, in=330, "id"]\\
G_2 \ar[ru, shift left=1.5pt, "g_2"] \ar[looseness=6, out=300, in=240, "id"]
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just mine it is a humble suggestion. Into the `\ar` command I suggest to improve the position of labels using the `pos=<value>` option into `\ar[...]` because `g_1` and `g_2` are too far away from the arrows (and I would decrease their character).

Comment: @Sebastiano, well, I didn’t give (now see enough) attention to this aspect of question. This can be improved with defining styles of labels, distances between nodes etc. How to do this, is described in package documentation. Since now is quite late in my time zone, so I will possible prepare a suggestion for better looking diagram example as you suggest.