how can i write quiver in latex?

I have been trying for hours but I could not write it as below. Can you help me?

Please show what you tried. This will give people a starting point to solve the problem.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/616721/208544

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I did something similar to this using the "chemfig" package
\documentclass[border=3mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \schemestart
    1 \arrow{->[a]} \chemfig{@{a1}2} \hspace{1cm}   b
    \chemmove{  
        \draw[shorten <=3pt,shorten >=3pt](a1).. controls +(30:18mm) and +(330:18mm)..(a1);
    }
    \schemestop
\end{document}


or, using information from the link quiver diagrams
\documentclass[border=3mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    $ \begin{tikzcd}
            1 \arrow[r,"a"] & 2 \arrow[out=30,in=330,loop] & b 
        \end{tikzcd} $
\end{document}



You can use tikz-cd. I present the “standard” loop and also a personalized one (play with the parameters).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzcdset{
  quiver loop right/.style={looseness=8,out=20,in=340},
}

\begin{document}

\[% standard loop
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.2em]
1 \arrow[r,"a"] & 2 \arrow[loop right,"b"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\[% personalized loop
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.2em]
1 \arrow[r,"a"] & 2 \arrow[quiver loop right,"b"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}



Looking at the image, it is observed that the tip of the arrow is that of the xy package. Therefore, I think the diagram originally comes from this package.

\documentclass[border=6mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@C=-.4pc{
1 \overset{a}{\to} & 2 \ar@(ur,dr)[]^b & 
}

\xymatrix@C=.7pc{
1 \ar[r]^{a} & 2 \ar@(ur,dr)[]^b & 
}
\end{document}


The first half of the display is a definite match, but this isn't necessarily the best way to produce a quality image.

@barbarabeeton You are absolutely correct in your statement. In my output, I showed on the left what the OP presented, while on the right the arrows should indeed all be of the same type to ensure better image quality. Thank you for the clarification!
